# How to add value to db and grid without auto post back?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

There are two `Combobox`s, one `button`, and a `GridView` in a page.

When I click  the button, the selected items of the `Combobox`s should be inserted to the `GridView` and at the same time updated in database.

When I click the button it should not perform a postback.  Users should be able to add lots ot records when hitting the submit button.

Comment: You are going to have to use AJAX or some web service to save the value to the database.

Comment: Use AJAX update panel : **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx**

Comment: You really should try to accept some answers.

Comment: You won't be able to update the database without sending a request from back to the server (aka a postback).  You can hide the fact that you are posting back from the user by using AJAX, but it's still happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Set a script function call in `OnClientClick` and return false from this method.
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx
2. In this client method use JQuery AJAX to call a web method to update the db.
   http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/
3. Add a row to the table with jquery methods that manipulate DOM.
   [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

Of course you can use an `UpdatePanel` but you have to insert the combo and the grid inside, so this is not going to save you server CPU and traffic.